# Lua macro: attempt to call global '__def' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Trying to run `dump(x)` macro example from http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaMacros :

```
$ lua -lmacro
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> __def 'dump(x) print(_STR(x).." = "..tostring(x))'
stdin:1: attempt to call global '__def' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

System: Cygwin x64.

Any ideas of what's wrong with `__def`? Thanks.

Comment: did you check that `macro` loaded properly? can try using `macro.define` in place of `__def` if you still get `a nil value` then the module is not loaded... actually you would get `attempt to index a nil value` if `macro` is not loaded when you attempt to call `macro.define`

Comment: LuaMacro is dependent on a patched version of Lua